# Migration to new server - "The requested page "/" could not be found."

Tags: drupal, webserver, migration

In following the procedure [outlined in the Wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) I find that in Step 10 ("log into drupal") I'm seeing the message `Page not found The requested page "/" could not be found.`  The drupal menu is not there.   The login form is there, and once I log in I get  the 404 message `The requested URL /civicrm was not found on this server.`

```
error_log:  File does not exist: /var/www/html/civicrm,
```

When I try drush:

```
drush up --debug  --uri htp://mycivi.site.org
Starting Drush preflight. [0.03 sec, 4.12 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                           [preflight]
Cache HIT cid: 7.0.0-commandfiles-0-81cc86c1995ab7206f383ec28ad43baf [0.05 sec, 4.21 MB]                                                                                                                                                                    [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.2 sec, 10.22 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.2 sec, 10.22 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command. [0.2 sec, 10.22 MB]                                                                              [error]
The drush command 'up htp://mycivi.site.org' could not be executed. [0.2 sec, 10.23 MB]                                                                                                                                                     [error]
```

I'm guessing the drupal restore from the source server did something to the drupal database on the target server that changed a path.

Source server drupal path = `/var/www/vhosts/contacts/httpdocs`

Target server drupal path = `/var/www/html`

Do these paths have to be identical for a migration to work? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ensure that the .htaccess file was transferred from the old to the new server?

Comment: Hi Laryn,   no I didn't, but just now went back and copied it over.   It did not make a difference.

Comment: Does the rest of the Drupal portion of the site work correctly? If not, I would focus there before getting on to the CiviCRM portion.

Comment: That was a good tip.   In the end I loaded the exact same version of Drupal as the source site 7.22 instead of 7.38  Everything looks as it should now. Thank you!

Comment: Great. I will add that as an answer below, then!

Comment: I strongly recommend **not running your site on Drupal 7.22**, since that will leave it vulnerable to multiple security issues including "Drupageddon". *Your site will be hacked pretty swiftly if this isn't addressed.* Now that the site is working, you should run the full Drupal upgrade. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have migrated Drupal correctly and all of the non-CiviCRM portions of the site function correctly.

- Sometimes the `.htaccess` file doesn't get transferred with FTP and
  it is an important file.
- Also, migrate the same filesystem/version
  from one server to the other, and be sure to upgrade as needed to
  keep things secure (either before or after the migration).

At that point if Drupal is working correctly you can focus on CiviCRM.

Answer (score 3):

If your site has been migrated to a different version of the Drupal codebase, then make sure you've run the database updates (`drush updb` or visit `update.php`)

This will update your Drupal DB to match the new codebase, and clear lots of caches etc as well.